# Why does my steak turn out underdone?

Tags: poultry

I take lots of advice to cook steak, but it always turns out underdone. I need help. I cook it at a higher temperature for longer times and nothing works.

Comment: What meat? You say "steak" but tag it "poultry"; unqualified "steak" usually refers to beef.  How are you cooking it?  How are you measuring how done it is?

Comment: Current cooking methods and past failures would also be extremely helpful in diagnosing any issues. Equipment used (such as non-stick pan vs. cast iron for example) can also provide some insight into what might be going wrong for you.

Comment: Don't cook it from frozen

Answer (score 1):

If you're ending up with undercooked foods, especially if they're getting done on the outside, but undone on the inside, you want *lower heat* for *longer* times. You can look up the ["reverse-sear" method](https://www.seriouseats.com/2017/03/how-to-reverse-sear-best-way-to-cook-steak.html) that involves baking the steak to desired doneness, then searing the outside to get a nice crust. Gordon Ramsey has a great video on YouTube about cooking steaks as well. Sous vide is another often-recommended cooking method, but that involves purchasing specialized equipment if you don't already have one. Something to research if that interests you though. :)

If you don't currently, use a quick-read digital meat thermometer to gauge how "done" the steak is. Google returns the table on this site when searching for "steak temps" to determine doneness.

https://www.heb.com/recipe/recipe-article/grill-times-temperatures-for-steak/1392677044707

You measure the temperature in the thickest part of the steak, so it's best to get a cut of meat that is as uniform in thickness as possible. Cooking from room-temperature also helps in getting the inside done while reducing the risk of burning the outside.

Comment: Isn't what you've described as 'Reverse Sear' is just 'sear and oven-finish'? [Reverse sear is the opposite[(https://jesspryles.com/recipe/how-to-cook-a-steak-with-reverse-sear-method/), cook the steak in the oven and then sear the surface when you know the middle is done enough for you.

Comment: @Spagirl You're totally right. I'll edit.